# CAML Query for SharePoint Online - ViewFields not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query, pnp, camlviewfields

I am trying to use PnP with CAML Query to retrieve all items in a document library where certain fields meet certain values. The query filter is working fine, it retrieves the correct documents, however I can't seem to get the ViewFields working. All it ever shows me no matter what is the Id, Title, GUID.

```
$listItems = Get-PnPListItem -List Documents -Query "<view><query>
<ViewFields>
  <FieldRef Name='MyChoice' />
  <FieldRef Name='FileRef' />
  <FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' />
</ViewFields>
<QueryOptions>
  <ViewAttributes Scope='RecursiveAll' />
  <Lists ServerTemplate='101' />
</QueryOptions>
<Where>
  <And>
           <Eq>
              <FieldRef Name='MyChoice' />
              <Value Type='MultiChoice'>Text Two</Value>
           </Eq>
           <Eq>
              <FieldRef Name='MySecurity' />
              <Value Type='MultiChoice'>Internal</Value>
           </Eq>
  </And>
</Where>
</Query>
</View>"
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Tested and working with this query $Query = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><RowLimit>300</RowLimit>
    <ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title'/><FieldRef Name='URL'/></ViewFields>
   <Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ContentType' /><Value Type='Computed'>Process Link</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"
 
    #get all list items using powershell sharepoint online - matching given query 
   $ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Query $Query

Answer (score 0):

When you are looking at the results you get back from Get-PnPListItem, if you do this:

```
$listItems | ForEach-Object {
$_ | Format-Table;
}
```

Then it will only show you id, Title and GUID. However, if you do this:

```
$listItems | ForEach-Object {
$_.FieldValues | Format-Table;
}
```

You will see that all of the requested field values are actually being returned. So in your case

```
$_['MyChoice']
```

should return

```
Text Two
```